# value should be populating in multipicklist field

Tags: formula

My senario is when i select one picklist field A and value 1,and Another picklist field B and value 2 after selecting these two picklist value a value 3 should be populating in multipicklist field.Can we do this formula and how.All fileds are picklist so which field we can make formula field.Plz reply..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Apex with code like:

```
if (record.Picklistone__c == 'value1' && record.Picklisttwo__c == 'value2')
{
    Set<String> vals = new Set<String>(record.MultiPicklist__c.Split(';'));
    vals.add('value3');
    record.MultiPicklist__c = String.Join(vals, ';');
}
```

For whatever reason, in formulas you are not allowed to treat a multi-picklist field as a single text field, so I'm not sure if something similar could be implemented via regular formulas.